# Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, dex, xposed-framework

I am using Android Studio and developing an Xposed Framework module. The majority of my users can use my application just fine, however two of them have an issue, which is pasted below. I have done some searching and attempts at fixing it (removing duplicate classes, changing the jar library my application needs from 'compiled' to 'provided') and no luck. It's difficult for me to debug this as well as I cannot reproduce the issue the users are experiencing. How can I resolve this issue?

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: Class ref in pre-verified class resolved to unexpected implementation 
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClassNative(Native Method) 
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.defineClass(DexFile.java:222) 
    at dalvik.system.DexFile.loadClassBinaryName(DexFile.java:215) 
    at dalvik.system.DexPathList.findClass(DexPathList.java:322) 
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:54) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:497) 
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.loadModule(XposedBridge.java:421) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.loadModules(XposedBridge.java:386) 
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:120) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I would get the users to reinstall xposed and start fresh if possible. When xposed was coping the jars over it may have done it incorrectly. Usually the fix for this error is changing the compile to provided but like you said it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

open module settings - app - dependencies

change the `xposed*.jar` scope to provided